# HP Printer Cartridge not recognised after moving country

Tags: printer

I have an HP Photosmart C4480 printer which was purchased in New Zealand (I used to live there). Now that I am living in the UK, I'm having trouble getting replacement print cartridges to work.

The cartridge numbers in NZ were 74 and 75. I've just purchased 350 and 351 as they list the C4480 on the box (74/75 not available in UK). However, I get "incompatible print cartridge" when using these. They're all genuine HP cartridges.

Is there something I need to do to reset the country the printer thinks it's in?

Comment: I've now heard of everything! Region locking on printers.

Comment: tell me about it!! ridiculous isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Contact HP support and they will take you through the process, I had to do this with a 6180 All-In-One.
It's painless and, if you take notes, you'll find out how to access the maintenance menu and some of it's functions for a bit of future tinkering.

Comment: thanks - this is the answer, although so far they've not been able to solve it, despite going through 45 minutes of support! Still, apparently they'll replace my printer if it doesn't work :)

Comment: I don't know if you've already used this HP contact method but it's much the same way I did it.   http://www.stinkyinkshop.co.uk/blog/2010/05/17/how-do-i-change-the-region-of-my-hp-printer/

Comment: Yes that's right - exactly the same as I've been through so far

Answer (score 0):

This is because your printer is area coded. we have been asked similar questions before from people who have bought printers not in the UK.